# Android BLE: Convert ScanResult timestampNanos to System nanoTime

Tags: android, bluetooth, timestamp, bluetooth-lowenergy

When scanning for Bluetooth Low Energy packets I receive ScanCallback with ScanResult being set. I can get "Device timestamp when the scan result was observed" with result.getTimestampNanos() but this time is not aligned with the Systems.nanoTime(). Is there a way to convert from one to the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following code to convert the getTimestampNanos() to system millis by using SystemClock.elapsedRealtime():

```
long rxTimestampMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - 
                         SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                         scanResult.getTimestampNanos() / 1000000;
```

This can be converted easily to a Date object:

```
Date rxDate = new Date(rxTimestampMillis);
```

Then you then get the time as a string:

```
String sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(rxDate);
```

Comment: Not sure why you prefixed your variables with `rx` or even `s`, but I don't think we need RxJava for this

Comment: tx and rx are common abbreviations for receive and transmit. I pasted this code from a source file which was using both a 'tx' and an 'rx' timestamp.  In this case the question was about receive timestamps so I left the rx prefix.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way to do that

````
long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - scanResult.getTimestampNanos(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)```
````

Comment: How could I scan periodically with different timestamps for Wifi since I only receive only one RSSI at one time for each scan